# spring clound eureka server dependencies error gradle intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

Am not able to add the `spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server` as dependencies in gradle project (IDE Intellij)

```
please find my build.gradle file below.

        plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'war'
    }

    group = 'com.lti.mod.services'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1')
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
        /*compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'*/
        compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:2.1.5.RELEASE')
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Please find the gradle build messages below.

```
        > Configure project : The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation configuration instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations
at build_5fewyf5k4gqf0wzmewce4q3ow$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\AngularCourse\core-services\build.gradle:30)
(Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile` configuration is deprecated in the Gradle 7.0 as your error message says. Please use `implementation` instead.

Check the docs - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations